# commercial use of fonts

Tags: fonts

Where can I find out whether a font is licensed or not?

Is **lilyUPC** for commercial use?

[LILYUPC](http://fontzone.net/font-details/LilyUPC/)

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://fontzone.net/terms/

> ***Intellectual Property Rights***
>
> The FontZone.net claims no ownership or control over any content submitted, posted or displayed by you on or through The FontZone.net. You or a third party licensor, as appropriate, retain all patent, trademark and copyright to any content you submit, post or display on or through The FontZone.net and you are responsible for protecting those rights, as appropriate. By submitting, posting or displaying content on or through The FontZone.net which are intended to be available to the members of the public, you grant The FontZone.net a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive perpetual license to reproduce, publish and distribute such content on The FontZone.net for the purpose of displaying and distributing The FontZone.net. The FontZone.net furthermore reserves the right to refuse to accept, post, display or transmit any content in its sole discretion.

Answer (score 2):

By Googling it and finding the author.

[LilyUPC must be licensed for any use.](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=272)